# How to open main frame?

Tags: java

How i can do for open a main frame, please look at my code, and correct, or tell me where i have a misstake.

This is a code for authorization window, and i want see the main frame when i click at the button "login". Please,help me. I don`t know how to do this. I sitting at this program more than 5 days.

```
public static void authorizationWindow(){
    JButton createAcc = new JButton("Створити новий аккаунт");
    JButton loginIntoMy = new JButton("Ввійти в існуючий");
    loginIntoMy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel  jPanelCreateAcc = new JPanel();
            JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Введіть ваш email:");
            JLabel passLabel = new JLabel("Введіть пароль :");
            JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
            JPasswordField pass =new JPasswordField(10);

            jPanelCreateAcc.add(nameLabel);
            jPanelCreateAcc.add(name);
            jPanelCreateAcc.add(passLabel);
            jPanelCreateAcc.add(pass);

            JButton login = new JButton("Ввійти");
            JButton cancel = new JButton("Вийти");


            login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String text =   name.getText();
                char[] password = pass.getPassword();
                System.out.println(" "+ text + ""+new String(password));




                }
            }); 

     //              Кнопка вийти має виходити повністю з програми

            cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);

                }
            });


            JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(createAcc,jPanelCreateAcc,"Вхід", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null,new Object[]{login,cancel},null);   





        }
    });

    int n =JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{createAcc,loginIntoMy}, null);


}
```

This is a main frame code:

```
private static Component createWindow(int width, int height,
        String title ) throws IOException {





    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.pack();
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.setSize(width, height);
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    window.add(jPanel);


    screenButton.setLocation(25, 59);



 //      jtb.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",1,14));

    jPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    jPanel.add(screenButton);
    jPanel.add(saveTextButton);

    jtb.setBackground(Color.green);
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jtb);
    jsp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 247));

    jpm.add(copy);
    jtb.setComponentPopupMenu(jpm);
    jPanel.add(jsp);

    jtb2.setBackground(Color.orange);
    JScrollPane jsp2 = new JScrollPane(jtb2);
    jsp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 247));
    jtb2.setComponentPopupMenu(jpm);

    jtb3.setBackground(Color.white);
    JScrollPane jsp3 = new JScrollPane(jtb3);
    jsp3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 247));
    jtb3.setComponentPopupMenu(jpm);

    jPanel.add(time());
    jPanel.add(jsp2);
    jPanel.add(jsp3);

    window.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
    jMenuBar.add(jMenu);
    jMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jMenuItem, "");

        }
    });




    // GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
    //
    // jPanel.setLayout(gbl);
    // GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    //
    // gbc.gridx = 0;
    // gbc.gridy = 0;
    //
    // gbc.weightx = 0.0 ;
    // gbc.weighty = 0.9;
    //
    // gbc.insets =new Insets(10,3,4,5);
    // gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

    return jMenu.add(jMenuItem);
}
```

And this is a thread:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    authorizationWindow();
            createWindow(1280, 720, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add something with the pseudo code of

```
if button_press == true then
    show main_frame
endif
```

This might help.

Comment: i trying with that, but not help

Comment: I am not to familiar with Java and main frames, but I just know enough to know to give you that pseudo code to try to work with. Sorry if I wasn't much help. I'm pretty new to this site and I mainly program in python.

Answer (score 0):

CR7, 
It doesn't look like all of your code is here but I can tell you that inside of your

```
authorizationWindow()
```

there is an action listener

```
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text =   name.getText();
            char[] password = pass.getPassword();
            System.out.println(" "+ text + ""+new String(password));
            }
        });
```

This is where you would make the main window call so it would look more like

```
        login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String text =   name.getText();
            char[] password = pass.getPassword();
            System.out.println(" "+ text + ""+new String(password));
            createWindow(1280, 720, "");
            }
        });
```

At your thread, Remove the createWindow(1280, 720, "");
Otherwise that would be creating the window simultaneously.

I'm assuming that you created "window" as a JFrame somewhere else in the program

Comment: yea i remove this method from thread. An object of main frame is a static